# Finding illustrative patterns in data

Tags: pattern-recognition

I am an engineering student and new to data science.

For my Bachelorthesis, I am evaluating how precise different algorithms for computing an upper bound on the global Lipschitz constant of a neural network are.

I have a bunch of data collected: the realtive error in Lipschitz-constant estimation for different network parameters (layer-sizes, number of layers, weights, biases etc.) and different algorithms.

I want to somehow find illustrative patterns in the data (I want to derive claims like f.ex: when networks have more neurons, the estimation is less precise, when there are more weights with negative sign...).

Do you think deriving such statements is possible using some data science techniques?
What topics should i look into for this? Any tips?

Thanks in advance.
I am grateful for any help.

Comment: Welcome to DatacienceSE. I'd recommend visualizing all the types of plot that you can think of with your variables in order to make sense of the data and try to find the patterns.